# Hide or delete Text with Button on Button Press in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to delete an element or you can say Text() (Just for example).
I need a code that will hide or delete the view as well as the button on button press event.

Here is my code.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  codespeedy
//
//  Created by CodeSpeedy on 19/07/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Hi")
                Button("Hi Button"){
                    // Action goes here --- Delete the above Text as well as the button
                }
                
            }
            HStack{
                Text("Hello")
                Button("Hello Button"){
                    // Action goes here --- Delete the above Text as well as the button
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Hola")
                Button("Hello Button"){
                    // Action goes here --- Delete the above Text as well as the button
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting that I will put some code in `Button("Hello Button"){ // Action goes here --- Delete the above Text as well as the button }`
Here, and on pressing the button it will delete the Text and button too...

Answer (score 0):

Make three `@State variables` that you can use to hide your views after clicking on your button.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var hidden1 = false
    @State private var hidden2 = false
    @State private var hidden3 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Hi")
                Button("Hi Button"){
                    hidden1.toggle()
                }
            }
            .isHidden(hidden1)
            
            HStack{
                Text("Hello")
                Button("Hello Button"){
                    hidden2.toggle()
                }
            }
            .isHidden(isHidden2)
            
            HStack {
                Text("Hola")
                Button("Hello Button"){
                    hidden3.toggle()
                }
            }
            .isHidden(hidden3)
            
        }
    }
}
```

and you can use this modifier function to hide your view's conditionally.

```
extension View {
        
    @ViewBuilder func isHidden(_ hidden: Bool, remove: Bool = false) -> some View {
        if hidden {
            if !remove {
                self.hidden()
            }
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this simple approach, using a simple var `selections` as shown in the
example code. It will carry out the action of the button **and**
`...Delete the above Text as well as the button`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selections = [true,true,true]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if selections[0] {
                HStack{
                    Text("Hi")
                    Button("Hi Button 0"){
                        // Action goes here --- Delete the above Text as well as the button
                        selections[0] = false
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if selections[1] {
                HStack{
                    Text("Hello")
                    Button("Hello Button 1"){
                        selections[1] = false
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if selections[2] {
                HStack {
                    Text("Hola")
                    Button("Hello Button 2"){
                        selections[2] = false
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

You can of course scale this approach to whatever number of buttons you want, such as:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selections: [Bool] = Array(repeating: true, count: 10)
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(selections.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            if selections[index] {
                HStack{
                    Text("Hi")
                    Button("Hi Button \(index)"){
                        // Action goes here
                        selections[index] = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showHi = true
    @State private var showHello = true
    @State private var showHola = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showHi {
                HStack {
                    Text("Hi")
                    Button("Hi Button") {
                        toggleShowHi()
                    }
                }
            }

            if showHello {
                HStack {
                    Text("Hello")
                    Button("Hello Button") {
                        toggleShowHello()
                    }
                }
            }

            if showHola {
                HStack {
                    Text("Hola")
                    Button("Hola Button") {
                        toggleShowHola()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func toggleShowHi() {
        showHi.toggle()
    }

    private func toggleShowHello() {
        showHello.toggle()
    }

    private func toggleShowHola() {
        showHola.toggle()
    }
}
```

try below code